# TypeError when trying to add CSV entry into Spreadsheet using Pandas and XLSXwriter

Tags: python, csv, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am currently trying to create a program that scans a CSV file and searches entries in the file using the BING API, the results are then pasted into a spreadsheet.

Part of this macro involves also pasting onto the spreadsheet what term is being searched, so I am effectively copying an entry from the CSV into a spreadsheet, which sounds pointless but serves a vital role.

My CSV looks like this:

```
EntryNumber Name    Company TitleNumber
123         john    hsbc    5555
124         chris   ford    6666
125         adam    apple   7777
```

I use Pandas to extract the data from the CSV by iterating it through it row by row, using this code:

for index,row in df.iterrows():

```
entrynumber = row['EntryNumber']
name = row['Name']
company = row['Company']
title = row['TitleNumber']
```

Then I try and write one of the variables to a cell in the spreadsheet using xlsxwriter:

```
worksheet.write(row, col, entrynumber)
```

However this generates a type error, the traceback is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSVtest.py", line 68, in <module>
    worksheet.write(row, col, entrynumber)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlsxwriter/worksheet.py", line 57, in cell_wrapper
    int(args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 92, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
Exception ignored in: <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x1088118d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 148, in __del__
Exception: Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.
```

No idea why this is happening, I've tried converting the variables to strings but the error still pops up, anyone got any ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated :) Thanks.

Comment: The *row* argument expects a single value on every iteration. Right now, you are passing an entire `series` to it as row becomes a series during the tuple(index, series) pairing. Hence, you get that error. Instead, I feel supplying that arg as `index`(row nos.) would be more apt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey everyone I figured out a solution incase anyone else is as stupid as me to make the same mistake.

Basically, as I was using XLSXWRITER I had a variable called 'row' to tell the module where to start writing data to the spreadsheet.
In my haze I completely forgot that I had also used that same name when I was iterating over the CSV file using PANDAS, using the code:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
```

Obviously this caused some sort of error as Python got mixed up between the two.

Anyway its unlikely but hopefully this can help someone who makes a similar mistake while learning!